# WPF ViewModel or not ViewModel

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding

I have business model (actually it is used to read data using Entity Framework 6) looks like:

```
class Profile : NameDescriptionBase
{
    public virtual float Rate {get;set;}
    public virtual float HoursPerWeek {get;set;}

    public virtual IList<Task> Tasks {get;set;}
}

class Task : NameDescriptionBase
{
    public enum TastStates
    {
        New, Finished, Stopped, InProgress
    }

    public virtual IList<Task> Tasks {get;set;}
    public virtual TastState {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<TimeSpan> LoggedPeriods {get;set}
}
```

I want to bind this model to the `TreeView` and it is working fine (via `HierarchicalDataTemplate`). But I want to customize each tree leaf to indicates each task current state as combobox so user be able to change it. And here I stuck.

I can implement service method in data context which provides bonding with `Tuple<int, string>` of TaskState values and ids, but I want to bind it to each task. My master view model (i.e. DataContext) looks like:

```
class MasterViewModel
{
   public List<Profile> Profiles {get;set;}
   public Profile CurrentProfile  {get;set}

   public List<Task> ActiveTasks {get;}
   public List<Tasl> FinishedTasks {get;}

   ....
}
```

So, current user profile and list of corresponding tasks updates fine, but looks like binding to properties of Entity itself does not works. As I understand it is expected - my entities does not implements INotifyPropertyChanged because it is not a view models.

So, is it right that only one way for my case to convert each Task to corresponding view model and after each action save its entity with updated fields to DB? Looks ugly.

Comment: did you added a view model?

Answer (score 2):

MVVM pattern intention is to provide View - Model separation in a first place. Since your view is a separate concept from the model it is perfectly fine to define an additional class in the view (so called view model) to represent your entity. Even if on each update your TaskViewModel will update the TaskEntity - nothing will be saved to db before you call SaveChanges().

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler example:

---

Using these three classes, you could easily display your profiles (read-only), but I bet you already knew that:

- ProfileEditor.xaml, your View

  - Has a control bound to `Profiles`
- ProfileEditorViewModel.cs, your ViewModel

  - Has `public ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }`
- Profile.cs, your Model

---

If you want to be able to alter your Model, with the View being responsive, you certainly must create a 'mini ViewModel'.  In this read-write implementation, you might have:

- ProfileEditor.xaml, your View

  - Has a control bound to `ProfileProxies`
- ProfileEditorViewModel.cs, your ViewModel

  - Has `public ICollection<ProfileProxy> ProfileProxies { get; set; }`
- ProfileProxy.cs, a 'mini ViewModel'

  - Wraps a `Profile`, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
- Profile.cs, your Model